# second game starts itself with wrong conditions in a python simle gui program

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to make a simple game using `simplegui` in python. In this game, a number is guessed between either `0-100` or `0-1000` (depending upon user's choice) and then the user guess that number. The user gets maximum 7 attempts. The new game starts after the user lose or guess the correct number. The game should run continously.

**Problem:** When the first game finishes...second game normally and then third game starts which prints the message **`You lose!`**.

My code is following:

```
import simplegui
import random
import math


# initialize global variables used in your code
numOfTurns = 0 
numberThought = 2000
maxAllowedTurns = 0
flag = 0 # 1: range is (0, 100] and 2: range is (0,1000]

# define event handlers for control panel
def range100():
    # button that changes range to range [0,100) and restarts
    global flag
    flag = 1
    new_game()

def range1000():
    # button that changes range to range [0,1000) and restarts
    global flag
    flag = 2
    new_game()

def input_guess(string_guess):
    guess = int(string_guess)
    global numberThought , numOfTurns, maxAllowedTurns, flag
    numOfTurns = numOfTurns + 1

    if ( numberThought > 1000 ):
        print "Please Select the Range First"
        print 
        return 
    # main game logic goes here 
    guessLeft = maxAllowedTurns - numOfTurns
    if(numberThought < guess):
        print "Your guess was = ", guess
        print "Number of Guesses remaining = ", (maxAllowedTurns - numOfTurns)
        print "Lower !"
        print 
        if (guessLeft == 0):
            print "You Lose!!"
            print "The Number was = ", numberThought
            print "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
            print
            print
            new_game()

    elif (guess < numberThought):
        print "Your guess was = ", guess
        print "Number of Guesses remaining = ", (maxAllowedTurns - numOfTurns)
        print "Higher !"
        print 
        if (guessLeft == 0):
            print "You Lose!!"
            print "The Number was = ", numberThought
            print "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
            print
            print
            new_game()

    elif (guess == numberThought):
        print "Your guess was = ", guess
        print "Correct !"
        print 
        new_game()
        if (guessLeft == 0):
            print "You Lose!!"
            print "The Number was = ", numberThought
            print "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
            print
            print
            new_game()                         

# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Guess The Number", 300, 300)
# register event handlers for control elements
frame.add_button("range (0,100]", range100)
frame.add_button("range (0,1000]", range1000)
frame.add_input("Enter",input_guess, 100)

# call new_game and start frame
# helper function to start and restart the game
def new_game():
    global numberThought , numOfTurns , flag, maxAllowedTurns
    numOfTurns = 0
    print "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    print "NEW GAME !!!!"
    # Defining the number of turns allowed based upon the range type
    if(flag == 1):
        maxAllowedTurns = 7
        numberThought = random.randrange(0,100)
        print "Range is from 0 - 100"
        print "Max allowed turns = " , maxAllowedTurns
        print "Number of Guesses remaining = " , maxAllowedTurns-numOfTurns
        print
    elif(flag == 2):
        maxAllowedTurns = 10
        numberThought = random.randrange(0,1000)
        print "Range is from 0 - 1000"
        print "Max allowed turns = " , maxAllowedTurns
        print

frame.start()
```

Comment: You need to re-initialize your global variables for each game. Or better yet, each game should have it's own local variables.

Comment: i did update the global variables in `new_game()`. And, the second game starts normally, it means the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I only looked at the code, I didn't test it (didn't want to install simplegui), but I think it prints you lose when you guess the correct number using exactly the allowed turns. Try removing the if block "if (guessLeft == 0): ... " in the last elif block in input_guess.

Comment: @user2746752: Thanks a lot ...it was really a silly mistake. You put your answer..i will upvote/choose your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Copy-pasted comment)

I only looked at the code, I didn't test it (didn't want to install simplegui), but I think it prints you lose when you guess the correct number using exactly the allowed turns. Try removing the if block "if (guessLeft == 0): ... " in the last elif block in input_guess.